# select con agrupaciones

Tags: plsql

**Se puede obtener en una única select???**

Un empresa ejemplo dni ,departamento y produccion realizada

Obtener el porcentaje de producción:  la produccion de la persona entre la producción de su departamente de su departamento ( produccion persona*100/ produccion departamento

- **Produccion del departamento:**

  ```
  select departamento, sum(produción) 
  from empresa
  group by departamento
  ```
- **Produccion del trabajador**

  ```
  select dni, departamento,sum(produción)
  from empresa
  group by dni,departamento
  ```

Comment: Podrias agregar la consulta que tienes para ayudarte

Comment: Como puedo agregar la consulta ?

Comment: En la pregunta dice editar, ahi puedes editar la pregunta y agregarla

Comment: El boton editar lo veo , edito la pregunta pero que es agregar? y como agrego?. gracias

Comment: Pegalo aqui y te ayudo a agregarlo

Comment: Se puede obtener en una única select???

Un empresa ejemplo dni ,departamento y produccion realizada

Obtener el porcentaje de producción: la produccion de la persona entre la producción de su departamente de su departamento ( produccion persona*100/ produccion departamento

--produccion del departamento select departamento, sum(produción) from empresa group by departamento

--produccion del trabajador select dni, departamento,sum(produción) from empresa group by dni,departamento

Comment: @luisjavier , ¿Pudiste probar mi SQL? Vi tu comentario tras haber publicado mi respuesta y no sé si llegaste a verla. Si no te funciona o tienes alguna consulta escribe un comentario en la respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La consulta que buscas es la siguiente:

```
SELECT
  dni, producción, producción,
  producción * 100 / suma porcentaje,
  emf.departamento, suma
FROM empresa emf
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    SUM(producción) suma,
    departamento
  FROM empresa
  GROUP BY departamento
) su
ON su.departamento = emf.departamento
```

Puedes ver el funcionamiento en línea en [este enlace](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5reyUnCZj145MAmvueX7eR/5) y se divide en dos partes.

La primera parte (la consulta interior) obtiene la suma de cada departamento y a la tabla resultado la llama `su` (el campo `suma` se accedería como `su.suma` si hubiera conflicto de nombres):

```
SELECT
  SUM(producción) suma,
  emj.departamento
FROM empresa
GROUP BY departamento
```

La segunda parte (la consulta exterior) relaciona cada empleado de la tabla `empresa` con los resultados totales obtenidos por la consulta anterior, por lo que cada registro obtenido tendrá asociado el total del departamento en el campo `suma`, pudiendo calcular `producción * 100 / suma` sin problemas en el campo `porc`.

Comment: Me funciona correctamente.Gracias

Comment: Buscando por otras paginas de plsql he encontrado otra solución, pero me entra la duda de cual es más optima.

Comment: Si no la compartes no podré compararlas. Si ésta soluciona tu problema deberías marcarla como correcta para que otra persona que tenga tu mismo problema sepa que esta duda fue respondida y podrá encontrar la solución aquí. Si quieres que comparemos el rendimiento de una u otra solución comparte la consulta editando tu pregunta (y avisándome con un comentario) o bien abre una nueva pregunta (en ese caso envíame también un comentario con el enlace).

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/138170/select-con-agrupaciones/138187?noredirect=1#comment258437_138187

Answer (score 0):

Buscando por otras paginas de plsql he encontrado otra solución, pero me entra la duda de cual es mas óptima

```
SELECT   emf.dni
         emf.producción,
         emf.producción *100 / SUM( emf.producción ) OVER( PARTITION BY emf.departamento ) porcentaje,
         emf.departamento,
         SUM( emf.producción ) OVER( PARTITION BY emf.departamento ) suma
FROM      empresa emf
ORDER BY dni
```

Comment: La primera desventaja que se me ocurre es que `OVER` y `PARTITION` no están soportados por todos los motores de bases de datos, por lo que tendrías problemas a la hora de portar tu aplicación de uno a otro. Voy a probar la diferencia de rendimiento en postgresql, que es el servidor que tengo disponible para probar la diferencia entre una y otra.

Comment: No estoy seguro de si los resultados pueden extrapolarse a MS SQL Server, pero en postgresql aparentemente son similares ambas consultas: [https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5reyUnCZj145MAmvueX7eR/8](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5reyUnCZj145MAmvueX7eR/8). La primera ejecución me dio la subconsulta como más rápida que la consulta, la segunda y tercera fue al contrario, y tras hacer la prueba en varias ocasiones me doy cuenta que parece depender de la carga del servidor donde se hacen las pruebas (lo siento, no tengo un servidor dedicado para hacer las pruebas en vacío). (continua)

Comment: He usado un `EXPLAIN` para obtener un análisis del tratamiento de los datos y lo primero que veo es que debería usarse `departamento` como índice para acelerar tanto el `PARTITION` como el `SUM` de la subconsulta.

Comment: Por otro lado hacer dos `OVER` (`SUM( emf.producción ) OVER( PARTITION BY emf.departamento )`) sobre los mismos datos sería un desperdicio de procesamiento, pero el optimizador de consultas detecta que se tratan de los mismos datos y los reutiliza. En definitiva, parecen tener un rendimiento muy similar pero yo usaría la subconsulta por poder usarla en un amplio número de servidores sin problemas de compatibilidad.

Comment: PD: Acabo de descubrir que MySQL 8.0 da soporte a esas instrucciones ([https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5reyUnCZj145MAmvueX7eR/9](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5reyUnCZj145MAmvueX7eR/9)) y que en éste la subconsulta es más del doble de rápida a `PARTITION` (quizá porque al ser implementación reciente no usa el optimizador de consultas aún).

Comment: Gracias por los comentarios